# Exporting/importing a Docker container failure under Windows

Tags: windows, docker, containers, export, offline

I must transfer a Docker Container (or its Image) running on Debian from one Windows server to another (the second one is not connected to the Internet, I cannot rebuild it *in situ*), and it fails.

1. When trying to use the `docker save` command on the source server to export the Image, there is an error:

```
PS D:\Share> docker save -o fraction_image fractions-image

Error response from daemon: failed to create process (&{Options:{KirdPath:C:\Program Files\Linux
 Containers KernelFile:kernel InitrdFile:initrd.img TimeoutSeconds:0 BootParameters:}
Name:xxx_svm UvmTimeoutSeconds:300 Uvm:0xc000006670 MappedVirtualDisks:[{HostPath:C:\ProgramData\docker\lcow\scratch\xxx.vhdx
ContainerPath:/tmp/scratch CreateInUtilityVM:true ReadOnly:false Cache: AttachOnly:false}
{HostPath:C:\ProgramData\docker\lcow\xxx\layer.vhd ContainerPath:/tmp/d2 CreateInUtilityVM:true ReadOnly:true
Cache: AttachOnly:false}]}) in utility VM: container xxx_svm encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a 
Windows system call: The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or 
container. (0xc0370109) extra info: {"CommandLine":"cat '/tmp/d2/usr/share/doc/libbz2-1.0/changelog.Debian.gz'",
"WorkingDirectory":"/bin","Environment":{"PATH":"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:"},
"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]
,"CreateInUtilityVm":true}
```

2. When trying to use the command `docker import` on the target server after a `docker export` on the source server to copy the Container itself, there is also an error:

```
PS D:\Share\fraction.tar> docker import .\fraction.tar coil_estimation

Error response from daemon: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: Failed to safefile.OpenRelative failed in Win32: 
open \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\xxx\usr\include\linux\netfilter\xt_connmark.h: Cannot create a file
when that file already exists. (0x1f) usr\include\linux\netfilter\xt_connmark.h
```

I must confess this is all gibberish. Does anyone has a clue on that topic ?

Docker configuration:
`docker info`

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  cluster: Manage Docker clusters (Docker Inc., v1.2.0)

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 20
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.2300)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.999GiB
 Name: RTAC-RUS023-FAT
 ID: D7XI:CFNK:YWVW:FUC2:7J3I:UCBJ:MMVE:6NXQ:E73U:A6KS:K7NX:KBB5
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

`docker version` (I must stick to 19.03.5)

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        2ee0c57608
 Built:             11/13/2019 08:00:16
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       2ee0c57608
  Built:            11/13/2019 07:58:51
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: I don't know about the first error, but the opposite of `docker save` is `docker load`.  You shouldn't normally need `docker import` (or its counterpart `docker export`).

Comment: I tried the two methods to achieve my goal: `docker save` / `load` for the Image, or `docker import` / `export` for the Container, but both fail (when `sav`ing in case 1., and when `import`ing in case 2.)